# How do I push files to remote server with Git

Tags: git

I am trying to push files to a remote server.
So far I have tried.

**remote server**

```
$ cd /var
$ mkdir repo && cd repo
$ mkdir test.git && cd test.git
$ git init --bare
$ cd hooks
$ touch post-receive
$ sudo chmod +x post-receive
```

**post-receive**

```
#!/bin/sh
git --work-tree=/var/www/testsite --git-dir=/var/repo/test.git checkout -f
```

**local**

```
$ cd /localrepo
$ git remote add test ssh://user@my-site.com/var/repo/test.git
$ git push test main
```

**output**

```
Enumerating objects: 917, done.
Counting objects: 100% (917/917), done.
Delta compression using up to 12 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (879/879), done.
Writing objects: 100% (917/917), 3.93 MiB | 2.61 MiB/s, done.
Total 917 (delta 518), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (518/518), done.
To ssh://user@my-site.com/var/repo/test.git
 * [new branch]      main -> main
```

**Expect**
I am expecting that after the push I should be able to see files in `/var/www/testsite` on the remote server but I can't find any files anywhere.

It seems as if the `post-receive` is not working

I am actually trying to follow step 12 from [this](https://devmarketer.io/learn/deploy-laravel-5-app-lemp-stack-ubuntu-nginx/)

Comment: I don't see you commit anything

Comment: Technically you cannot push *files* at all, you can only push commits. But you are in fact pushing some commit(s) so that the `main` branch gets created. It does seem that your post-receive hook is not running. Debugging this is a bit tricky and generally has to be done on the server.

Comment: What is your active branch on the server? Is that `main`, or `master`?

Comment: @kosist  active branch is `main`

Comment: @AlexLarionov The commits being pushed are the commits to `origin main` which is pushed to git hub. I am told that doing what I did should create a copy on the my remote server

Comment: @kosist you are right... it was actually master! doh!

Comment: Please do not answer the question in the Question. If you have a solution, either delete the question or give the answer as an Answer. (Answering your own question is just fine on Stack Overflow.)

Answer (score 1):

The problem turned out too be the fact that active branch on the server was 'master' and I was pushing to 'main. (Thanks @kosist for pointing this out).

**Solution**

Change active branch on server with

```
echo ref: refs/heads/main > HEAD
```

or

```
git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/main
```

or specifying the branch in the `post-receive` hook (the option I chose)

```
git --work-tree=/var/www/laravel --git-dir=/var/repo/site.git checkout -f main
```